# Configure CAS from existing .NET Usernames/Passwords

Tags: .net, hash, forms-authentication, cas

Currently our website uses .NET Forms Authentication with salted SHA1 password hashes stored in a SQL Server 2005 database.  We want to change over to use a [CAS Server](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Home) for authentication, but we don't want to loose our existing usernames/passwords.

I figure I have two options... I can use the QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler and recreate the hashes in T-SQL, or I can use the DefaultPasswordEncoder if I can replicate the exact settings that .NET Forms Authentication uses. [Both are documented here.](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/JDBC)

**Has anyone tried to configure CAS to read .NET password hashes?**  If so, do you have an example using one of the methods above (or a third that I haven't thought of)?

Comment: Did you try adding a username and existing SHA1 salted password in the CAS backing userstore? I had a an Apache Directory Server sitting behind my CAS server and it handled my .NET Salted SHA1 passwords perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have an example ready unfortunately, but I know for certain that folks have done this by leveraging the functionality in the two classes you pointed out.

If you're looking for additional info and examples on how this may be done, please post a message to @cas-user mailing list.